# XMLHttpRequest cannot load when I'm not logged in

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

When I'm logged into **subdomain.mysite.com**,the asynchronous job listings will load and display as they should. When I'm not logged in, I get an infinite loading sign. I used inspect element and found this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://jobs.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://jobs.mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access. (index):

I have been trying to resolve this. I'm just learning the basics of PHP and I have no idea where to start troubleshooting.

Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to being logged in or not.

The problem is that sometimes you use HTTP and sometimes you use HTTPS but you always try to access the API over HTTPS.

The Same Origin Policy requires that the scheme be the same for the page the JavaScript is hosted in and the URL it is requesting the data from.

Use relative URIs.